# showing a field of type list in django admin

Tags: python, django

I am new to django so don't know much about it. my problem is that i am using multiselect in models in one field. S when i am trying to show that field in admin using list_display, it's giving an error of unhashable type:list. please help.

my models.py::

```
language = MultiSelectField(
               choices = LANG_CHOICES,
               null = False,
               blank = False,
               )
```

my admin.py::

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Newspapers

class NewspaperAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ['id','language','title','price']
```

and error is:

```
TypeError at /admin/newspapers/newspapers/
unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: post the complete model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a function to define language more effectively to django.. and than use it in list_display.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Newspapers

class NewspaperAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('id','get_languages','title','price')

    def get_languages(self, obj):
       return ",".join([l for l in obj.language])
```

Comment: nothing changed.. it's still showing the same error.. the error is just because of the language field. when i remove language from list display it works fine..

Comment: Can you try to remove language, to see if problem comes from him. Your multipleselectfield, store as CharField of comma-separated values, right ??

Comment: Thanks for helping.. this worked with a little change.. after applying this the error changed to ' "list" object has no attribute "all" '. So i tried by removing all() .. and it worked..  can you explain what happened here??

Comment: the previous solution that you gave of defining a function worked.. with a simple change.. its not showing now.

Comment: Edit the solution with your modification. How is store in your database this field language? Many-to-many? ChardField ?

Comment: I think it was stored as a type list.. because all the errors mentioned list.. i will check more and will reply again.. thank you though. highly appreciate your help